# Sender profile " From Name" editing

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, sfmcadmin

I currently have a sender profile setup in which "From Name" looks like **"Abc Def"** and I want to change it to **"Abc"**. Can this have any impact on deliverability, as this is main sender profile used for all sends and I don't want to have issues with it. The "From Email" will remain the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the sender name, while keeping the email address will not impact your deliverability. What is deciding your reputation is the combination of your sender domain and IP address.